# How do I craft this constant to a specific accuracy?

Tags: arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

An earlier post was migrated to [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44017/15901) and we determined that if this converged, we would have a constant close to the mass of the proton in kilograms.  This constant is constructed by summing the reciprocals of the products of all the numbers between consecutive squares.

Per this:

```
SumConvergence[10^-26/Pochhammer[m^2 + 1, 2 m], m]
```

(* True *)

we have convergence and thus a constant.  However, the following:

```
Sum[10^-26/Pochhammer[m^2 + 1, 2 m], {m, \[Infinity]}]
```

outruns the precision.

My question: Is there a way to use this sum to create the constant to a specified accuracy?

Comment: To be sure, the common opinion on physics.se of the meaning of this sum is that it is a sheer coincidence that it is close to the proton mass in kg.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I just got the Popular Question badge --- 1000 views and only 2 votes. Yes, they don't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, you can factor out the tiny portion of your constant, so:

```
NSum[1/Pochhammer[m^2 + 1, 2 m], {m, 1, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] 1*^-26
   1.6726218229590580987863882056891582636342622102204*10^-27
```

OTOH,

> ...products of all the numbers between consecutive squares.

```
Product[j, {j, (k - 1)^2, k^2}]
   Pochhammer[(-1 + k)^2, 2 k]
```

This doesn't resemble what you have.